# Newbie struggling removing objects from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to remove an element based upon its variables within its own class instance.

I have a class called Account, and an ArrayList called AccountList. As far as I know, there are two ways to remove an element from an array: by index and by using the Object 0 method.

Unfortunately, neither of these will work for me; I need to remove an object if it has a variable value of "accountNumber" (from the Account class) equals to the parameter value for AccountNumber entered by a user. My tutor wants a boolean method with a String parameter named Account Number.

My approachwould be to use the Account class's `getAccNumber()` getter method, and remove it if it's equal to the parameter.

```
public boolean removeAccount(String AccountNumber)

{   

    if (AccountNumber.equals(Account.getAccNumber()))
    {

        accounts.remove(AccountNumber);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work.

As an aside, I've had to make the `getAccNumber()` method static to allow access by the ArrayList class. This has messed up the instances of Account; if I create a new instance of it, the new AccountNumber value overwrites the previous.

Any ideas?

edit... his exact spec for it "removeAccount(String)    Should remove the Account with the account number specified as a parameter if it the Account exists. The appropriate boolean value should then be returned via a BlueJ ‘method result’ dialog box."

Comment: What is the type of `accounts`?

Comment: Use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to loop through the contents of the array list.  There is a `remove()` method in the `Iterator` interface which will allow you to safely remove entries while looping.

Comment: Is there another way?  I understand you're totally right but i know its not what my tutor is looking for :( could i do similar using a for or while loop?

Comment: accounts is the name of my arraylist, sorry to forget that!

Comment: `Account.getAccNumber()` Account is not defined anywhere where are you getting that

Comment: There are lots of other ways.  Without knowing what the constraints on your assignment are, however, I can't guess which will be acceptable to you.

Comment: @Dave95 How is `accounts` defined? Is it just `ArrayList accounts` or `ArrayList<...> accounts`?

Comment: Your idea is correct you just need to iterate over list comparing the passed accountnumber to each element and removing those that are equal using the current index...

Comment: Yeah i know i need to be more precise my bad haha, brso05 getAccNumber is a method from the Account class, which i'm trying to use to find the account number & compare it against the param.

Comment: he just doesn't want us to iterate which is annoying!

Comment: You should have many Account objects in your accountList object...

Comment: it's ArrayList<String> accounts

Comment: so are you comparing the given account number with an element in the accountlist?

Comment: yes that exactly what i'm doing amaleemur, comparing the param against the element in the arraylist, this element contains the variable (AccountNumber) amongst others.

Comment: @Dave95 have you considered using a for each loop to iterate through the values of the array?

Comment: I have considered this, if it's a match return true, otherwise fall out of the loop if no values match and fall straight into a return false statement? this sounds good, but i wasn't sure? this should still allow boolean to be the type shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make accountNumber static what you want to do it loop though the List of accounts and read each account number and compare them.

This should do the trick for you :

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{   
    return accounts.remove(getAccountByName(accountNumber));
}

public Account getAccountByName(String accountNumber){
     for(Account acc: accounts){
         if(accountNumber.equals(acc.getAccNumber())){
             return acc;
         }
     }    
}
```

The way you had it you would have reached a state where you would have got [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) read more on that.

Comment: won't i get a error because my boolean has no return statement? & also does that mean i have to create a new method called getAccountByName?

Comment: Yes i have created one for you ! hopefully it should fit in correctly ! Check the edit !

Comment: Sounds like my tutor has been a bit of a knob on this one as we're not allowed to use iterators nor create new method to do it!! i just can't get my head around how i would do it within the original method?

Comment: (Psst @StackFlowed, you might also want to check getAccountByName; I'd hate for the accounts to go on by without a match!)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you must iterate over your list until you find the element to remove, then remove it.  There are several ways to implement the details, but if you're using the standard `java.util.ArrayList` then I would recommend using its iterator.  Nothing prevents you from wrapping that operation in a method, but you seem in part to be confused about what class should have the `removeAccount()` method.

It should not be a method of your `Account` class, because that class shouldn't know anything about your list (so in particular, the `accounts` variable should not be a member of that class).  It could be a static method of `Account` if you were passing both the account number and the list, but that's not what you're doing.

Instead, you need to put the method on the class to which the `accounts` variable belongs, or on an inner class of that class, else your method has no access to the list.  At your level you should not be trying to figure out inner classes, so that leaves the class to which `accounts` belongs.

Comment: Sorry, i obviously haven't explained myself, reading back i'm confusing myself haha, accounts is the name of my arraylist, i defined using ArrayList<String> accounts. removeAccount() must be part of AccountList (the array list class).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it without any kind of iteration, in Java 8:

```
accounts.removeIf(account -> accountNumber.equals(account.getAccNumber()));
```

This expression returns `true` if something was removed, `false` if not.

If you can't use Java 8: I'm not sure just what you are and are not allowed to use.  If you can use loops, but you can't use an `Iterator` or an enhanced `for` loop (`for Account acc : accounts`), which uses an iterator by implication, you can write a loop using an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
    if (accountNumber.equals(accounts.get(i).getAccNumber())) {
        accounts.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

This finds the index of the account with the matching index, then uses the `remove(index)` method to remove it.  [Note that this approach has to be modified if you need to remove more than one, because the `remove(i)` method shifts all the indexes of the elements following element `i`, which means the `i++` could skip over one if you're not careful.  But I'm assuming there's at most one account with a given account number.]

Comment: This looks the nearest to what he was expecting to be honest, thats exactly what it needs to output for me! will this still be a boolean type method though?

Comment: `removeIf` is a `boolean` method.  What you do with the result, if anything, depends on what you need.

Comment: That's brilliant, thankyou very much! Never been actually lectured on this but apart from a for each loop ii can't think of another solution! perhaps he expected extra reading to teach us this? haha

Comment: The index one looks spot on and I'll try implement it tomorrow, thankyou very much for your excellent answer :)